# Giving specific values to pixels in some selected region

Tags: matlab, roi

I'm trying to do the following in `MATLAB`:

- Select some region of interest
- Give the pixels in that region the value `1` for instance

I'm not sure, would `imfreehand` be a starting point here for selecting the region of interest. What then?

How can this be done in `MATLAB`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short sample. Since you mentioned `imfreehand`, I included that but depending on what type of ROI you want to create, `impoly` or `imrect` may do a better job:

```
img = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
imshow(img);
roi = imfreehand;
img2 = img;
img2(roi.createMask) = 1;
imshow(img2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and nice answer. We can use `roi = imfreehand`, right? Is there a purpose of using `gca` in `roi = imfreehand(gca);`?

Comment: You are right. `gca` is the default value when omitted. My previous Matlab program dealing with ROI had multiple sets of axes, which forced me to specify which axes `imrect` had to use. In this simple case, there is no need to specify that. I changed the code to reflect your suggestion.