# createMask and function call syntax

Tags: matlab, function, methods, call, mask

As a follow up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363617/giving-specific-values-to-pixels-in-some-selected-region/18366918#18366918):

- What does `createMask` actually do? I went to the description from MathWorks [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/imroi.html#addnewposcbk), but wan't much clear.
- If you see in the answer of my question referenced above: `img2(roi.createMask) = 1;`, the part `roi.createMask` reminds me of **function call**, is that what we are really doing here? Calling the `createMask` function?

Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help? Do you need additional clarification?

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
img = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
imshow(img);
roi = imfreehand(gca);
img2 = img;
img2(roi.createMask) = 1;
imshow(img2);
```

`roi` is the handle to the object generated by `imfreehand`. One of the methods (~functions) available through the object (using the handle) is `createMask`, which can be accessed with the `.` operator. The method generates a type `logical` array of the same size as the pixel dimensions of the image. Values in the logical array are either `1` or `0` with values of `1` assigned to entries in the region corresponding to the area selected with the `imfreehand` operation. The operation `img2(roi.createMask) =1;` indexes into the image `img2` (it picks elements in `img2`) using the positions in the logical array with value `1` and assigns those elements value `1`.